# how to force tooltips to popup if textbox is empty in c#?

Tags: c#, tooltip

How to force a tool-tip to appear on text box when the text box is empty?

[image]

Comment: Look at the [`tooltip class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [`TextBox Events`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx) I'm sure you would be able to piece something together with `MouseEnter` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Client side script such as JS to display the tool tip.
There are few example on the below website to get it done using JQuery.

https://jqueryui.com/tooltip

Answer (score 0):

```
MyForm : Form
{
   private readonly Tooltip _toolTip = new ToolTip();

   public MyForm()
   { 
       InitialiseComponent();
       UpdateTips();
   }

   private void tbName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
   { 
      UpdateTips();
   }

   private void UpdateTips()
   {
      string tip =  string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbName.Text) 
             ? "You should supply some text here" 
             : null;

     _toolTip.SetToolTip(tbName, tip);
   }

}
```

Let's examine what is happening here.

1. We have a function `UpdateTips()` which looks to see whether `tbName` has an empty string as it's `Text` value.
   If it does, it will set the toolTip for `tbName` to the text message `"You should supply some text here"` - of course you can substitute any string here.
   If is is not empty it sets th toopTip for `tbName` to null (ie don't show a tool tip.
2. We have added code in the `TextChanged` event handler to call the `UpdateTips` method.
3. We also call the `UpdateTips` method from the constructor to ensure that we have the tool tip right from the start, if it is needed.

Comment: Lets say my textbox code is as below:

 private void tbName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

And my tooltips for the textbox is:

private void UsernameTip_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

What shud i add to let my tooltips trigger only when empty textbox is detected?